# Create a list with items from another list at indices specified in a third list

Tags: python

Consider two lists:

```
a = [2, 4, 5]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I want a resulting list `c` where

```
c = [0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0 ,0 ,0 ,0]
```

is a list of length `len(b)` with values taken from `b` defined by indices specified in `a` and zeros elsewhere.

What is the most elegant way of doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with the [conditional expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) and [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#enumerate).

This LC will iterate over the index and the value of the list `b` and if the index `i` is found within `a` then it will set the element to `v`, otherwise it'll set it to 0.

```
a = [2, 4, 5]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

c = [v if i in a else 0 for i, v in enumerate(b)]

print(c)
# [0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Note: If `a` is large then you may be best converting to a set first, before using `in`. The [time complexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) for using `in` with a list is O(n) whilst for a set it is O(1) (in the average case for both).

The list comprehension is roughly equivalent to the following code (for explanation):

```
c = []
for i, v in enumerate(b):
    if i in a:
        c.append(v)
    else:
        c.append(0)
```

As you have the option of using `numpy` I've included a simple method below which uses initialises an array filled with zeros and then uses list indexing to replace the elements.

```
import numpy as np

a2 = np.array(a)
b2 = np.array(b)

c = np.zeros(len(b2))
c[a2] = b[a2]
```

When timing the three methods (my list comp, my numpy, and Jon's method) the following results are given for `N = 1000`, `a = list(range(0, N, 10))`, and `b = list(range(N))`.

```
In [170]: %timeit lc_func(a,b)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.56 ms per loop

In [171]: %timeit numpy_func(a2,b2)
100000 loops, best of 3: 14.8 µs per loop

In [172]: %timeit jon_func(a,b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 22.8 µs per loop
```

This is to be expected. The numpy function is fastest, but both Jon's function and the numpy are **much faster** than a list comprehension. If I increased the number of elements to 100,000 then the gap between numpy and Jon's method gets even larger.

*Interestingly enough though, for small `N` Jon's function is the best!* I suspect this is to do with the overhead of creating numpy arrays being trumped by the overhead of lists.

Moral of the story: large N? Go with numpy. Small N? Go with Jon.

Comment: you missed `else: c.append(0)` in explanation. Awesome solution by the way.

Comment: Looks good, although isn't `in` kind of expensive to be running for all `i` in `enumerate(b)`? Suppose `a` and `b` are very long.

Comment: Indeed I do have the option for numpy.

Comment: not necessarily numpy, but it wouldn't be nearly as "elegant" as list comprehension

Answer (score 5):

The other option is to pre-initialise the target list with `0`s - a fast operation, then over-write the value to the suitable index, eg:

```
a = [2, 4, 5]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

c = [0] * len(b)
for el in a:
    c[el] = b[el]

# [0, 0, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: I may be mistaken, but python lists are not built like arrays. If they are not arrays, than it would be pretty expensive to replace an element inside of list.

Comment: @Rusty accessing/settings element are O(1) (Python `list`'s are arrays (just needn't be of homogeneous types) - not linked lists like the name could possibly imply)